# Is it possible to give more readable names for evolution sql scripts?

Tags: java, playframework

Play2.x
Is it possible to give more readable names for evolution sql scripts instead of {1,2,3-N}.sql?
In case I've made a mistake in one of them it quite difficult to find where without grepping.
F.e. 1-items-create.sql, 2-items-update.sql, 3-order-create.sql, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the source files](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L101), unfortunately it is not possible to use other names:

```
def updateEvolutionScript(db: String = "default", revision: Int = 1, comment: String = "Generated", ups: String, downs: String)(implicit application: Application) {
    ...
    val evolutions = application.getFile("conf/evolutions/" + db + "/" + revision + ".sql");
```

The `revision` parameter is `Int` type, not `String`.